# Full LCL error when running private nodes

Tags: stellar-core

I have set up a private Network by three Nodes. After running sometime, showing below message from Node2.

```
2019-05-27T09:49:55.006 GCTXZ [Ledger ERROR] Full LCL: { hash = 09205f2337afe335bc354911826806725ec55f9aef0589fadb6814dc5d6660a9,
  header = {
    ledgerVersion = 10,
    previousLedgerHash = ccc8ce41d4a0fe2b7416b0da8023a07ff5686c84b83ddf3b252100b61f7693e2,
    scpValue = {
      txSetHash = bda59da75bb656051bd6eece1b0e2c8b13781d6e3c1555802a63da8b5e324582,
      closeTime = 1558950409,
      upgrades = [
      ],
      ext = {
        v = 0
      }
    },
    txSetResultHash = ae290f4b0a8a18fdc2d9eae9d57f0f5776d733a5a3fda972befdc72459e282d8,
    bucketListHash = ab29c08ced8f374d1d82b686b383eee5021698e1940718c6e3e99ca87f76815f,
    ledgerSeq = 6731356,
    totalCoins = 1000000000000000000,
    feePool = 140900000,
    inflationSeq = 0,
    idPool = 842958,
    baseFee = 100,
    baseReserve = 100000000,
    maxTxSetSize = 100,
    skipList = [
      e203d6c9e085eff074b58add54fedbfeb1770d6a8a9c0e82226c928ea499d25a,
      4bede70f4a7f0a87b1cebc670f4338388476ecbfeb1853d9e41bbb13da9ac626,
      7f55b127b8e826290b30020742467771f82281e072176ce8408bcccae60abe70,
      bec12a563c4318ebf3ca908bfd583695369d2f5e0d241d49375e4c173939e611
    ],
    ext = {
      v = 0
    }
  },
  ext = {
    v = 0
  } }
 [LedgerManagerImpl.cpp:811]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  txset mismatch
```

Comment: How long is "some time"? Hours, days, weeks?

Comment: I have monitored it and check that after few minutes getting above error.